# Linux - proc_fs implementation in a basic kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

So I am trying to implement and see how does a module creates a virtual file in `/proc` and this is a very simple code I wrote:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 48

struct proc_dir_entry *proc_entry,*root_dir=NULL;
char result_buffer[BUF_SIZE];
char before[BUF_SIZE];
int count,temp=1;

ssize_t write(struct file *f, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{ 
  printk(KERN_ERR "my4: Somebody toyed here\n");
  if (copy_from_user(result_buffer,buf,len))
    return -EFAULT;
  return len;
}
// this read implementation is just a fudge, i am just trying to get the grasp of basic concepts here
ssize_t read(struct file *f, char __user *buf, size_t c, loff_t *off)
{
  int len = 0;
  if (temp == 0) {
    temp = 1;
    return 0;
  }
  sprintf(before,"[%s]",result_buffer);
  if (count <= 1)
    sprintf(result_buffer,"my4 read %d\n",count++);
  else 
    sprintf(result_buffer,"my4 read again!! count=%d\n", count++);
  len = strlen(result_buffer);
  if (copy_to_user(buf, result_buffer, len)) return -EFAULT;
  printk(KERN_ERR "my4: page before=[%s]\n\t page after=[%s]\n", before, result_buffer);
  temp = 0;
  return len;
}

static const struct file_operations file_ops = {
  .owner = THIS_MODULE,
  .read  = read,
  .write = write
};

int init_my4(void) {
  count = 1;
  proc_entry = proc_create("my4", 438, NULL, &file_ops);
  strcpy(result_buffer, "initialized\n");

  if (proc_entry == NULL) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "my4: could not create proc entry\n");
    return -ENOMEM;
  }
  printk(KERN_INFO "my4: Module loaded successfully\n");

  return 0;
}

void unload_my4(void) {
  remove_proc_entry("my4",root_dir);
  printk(KERN_INFO "my4: Module unloaded successfully\n");
}

module_init(init_my4);
module_exit(unload_my4);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

What the problem is that `BUF_SIZE` being just 48 if I write more than that to the file like :

```
echo "Lets write more than 48 bytes to the file and see if it breaks or overflows or if the kernel kills my process" > /proc/my4
```

Now when I `cat /proc/my4` I get:

```
my4: Somebody toyed here
[23482.029609] my4: page before=[[Lets write more than 48 bytes to the file and see if it breaks my4 read again!! count=3
]
     page after=[my4 read again!! count=3
```

I fail to understand what is happening here that is how does the kernel simply ignores the input greater than 48 bytes and where does it go?
As I thought that either it will overflow with a `segfault` or the kernel will kill the process!

Comment: Probably, exceeded characters from input string are stored in 'before' array, as its definition comes after `result_buffer`. Your module is incorrect, by kernel doesn't check array boundaries automatically. The same is true for user-space programs, written in C. Is this new for you?

Comment: No I know that there is no bound checking in C that is why I am confused as why it stops at the size mentioned as if there is a bound checking and yes kernel space mess is totally new to me

Comment: When you write string of 109 characters into file, you overflow not only `result_buffer` array, but also `before` one, and, probably, corrupt `count` and `temp` variables. When you read file, your call `sprintf` function with string of undefined length(`result_buffer`) and destination buffer(`before`) overlaps it. This is clean undefined behaviour. And your `dmesg` output is actually some sort of mess: `if it breaks my4 read again`. How you deduce bounds checking from that?

Comment: `count` variable does not get corrupted according to the output I have seen but I don't know about `temp`.`result_buffer` is not undefined and has a size `BUF_SIZE`.If you are talking about the input that I give to it then that is exactly my question.

Comment: `BUF_SIZE` is a **size** of the array `result_buffer`. But `sprintf` needs **length** of the string in it, so it searches NULL-byte. Because of overflow in `copy_from_user()` call, each character in the array is non-NULL, so NULL-byte is *somewhere after* the array. That's why I say **length** is undefined. Again, how you deduce bounds checking from your `dmesg` output?

Comment: I guess because it stopped at the length it should stop and ignored the rest of the input.

Comment: Your output contains string "Lets write more than 48 bytes to the file and see if it breaks" of length 62, which is more that `BUF_SIZE`. Instead of guessing, just print content of `result_buffer` and `before` in your `write` function after `copy_from_user()` call.